# JsonPath expression filtering based on "contains"?

Tags: jsonpath

I have a sample `Json` response as followed below
I know how to filter it using comparison actions like `==` or `>`
e.g. I can use `$.books[?(@.pages > 460)]` to retrieve books with more than 460 pages or
similarly `$.books[?(@.pages != 352)]` to retrieve books with not 352 pages.
But how can I filter this `Json` to retrieve books with title containing "Java" substring or published in 2014 year (actually substring too)?
The sample `Json` is:

```json
{  
  "books": [  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781593275846",  
      "title": "Eloquent JavaScript, Second Edition",  
      "subtitle": "A Modern Introduction to Programming",  
      "author": "Marijn Haverbeke",  
      "published": "2014-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "No Starch Press",  
      "pages": 472,  
      "description": "JavaScript lies at the heart of almost every modern web application, from social apps to the newest browser-based games. Though simple for beginners to pick up and play with, JavaScript is a flexible, complex language that you can use to build full-scale applications.",  
      "website": "https://eloquentjavascript.net/"  
    },  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781449331818",  
      "title": "Learning JavaScript Design Patterns",  
      "subtitle": "A JavaScript and jQuery Developer's Guide",  
      "author": "Addy Osmani",  
      "published": "2012-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",  
      "pages": 254,  
      "description": "With Learning JavaScript Design Patterns, you'll learn how to write beautiful, structured, and maintainable JavaScript by applying classical and modern design patterns to the language. If you want to keep your code efficient, more manageable, and up-to-date with the latest best practices, this book is for you.",  
      "website": "https://www.addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/"  
    },  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781449365035",  
      "title": "Speaking JavaScript",  
      "subtitle": "An In-Depth Guide for Programmers",  
      "author": "Axel Rauschmayer",  
      "published": "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",  
      "pages": 460,  
      "description": "Like it or not, JavaScript is everywhere these days-from browser to server to mobile-and now you, too, need to learn the language or dive deeper than you have. This concise book guides you into and through JavaScript, written by a veteran programmer who once found himself in the same position.",  
      "website": "https://speakingjs.com/"  
    },  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781491950296",  
      "title": "Programming JavaScript Applications",  
      "subtitle": "Robust Web Architecture with Node, HTML5, and Modern JS Libraries",  
      "author": "Eric Elliott",  
      "published": "2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",  
      "pages": 254,  
      "description": "Take advantage of JavaScript's power to build robust web-scale or enterprise applications that are easy to extend and maintain. By applying the design patterns outlined in this practical book, experienced JavaScript developers will learn how to write flexible and resilient code that's easier-yes, easier-to work with as your code base grows.",  
      "website": "https://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000262/index.html"  
    },  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781593277574",  
      "title": "Understanding ECMAScript 6",  
      "subtitle": "The Definitive Guide for JavaScript Developers",  
      "author": "Nicholas C. Zakas",  
      "published": "2016-09-03T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "No Starch Press",  
      "pages": 352,  
      "description": "ECMAScript 6 represents the biggest update to the core of JavaScript in the history of the language. In Understanding ECMAScript 6, expert developer Nicholas C. Zakas provides a complete guide to the object types, syntax, and other exciting changes that ECMAScript 6 brings to JavaScript.",  
      "website": "https://leanpub.com/understandinges6/read"  
    },  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781491904244",  
      "title": "You Don't Know JS",  
      "subtitle": "ES6 & Beyond",  
      "author": "Kyle Simpson",  
      "published": "2015-12-27T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",  
      "pages": 278,  
      "description": "No matter how much experience you have with JavaScript, odds are you don’t fully understand the language. As part of the 'You Don’t Know JS' series, this compact guide focuses on new features available in ECMAScript 6 (ES6), the latest version of the standard upon which JavaScript is built.",  
      "website": "https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/es6%20&%20beyond"  
    },  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781449325862",  
      "title": "Git Pocket Guide",  
      "subtitle": "A Working Introduction",  
      "author": "Richard E. Silverman",  
      "published": "2013-08-02T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",  
      "pages": 234,  
      "description": "This pocket guide is the perfect on-the-job companion to Git, the distributed version control system. It provides a compact, readable introduction to Git for new users, as well as a reference to common commands and procedures for those of you with Git experience.",  
      "website": "https://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561/index.html"  
    },  
    {  
      "isbn": "9781449337711",  
      "title": "Designing Evolvable Web APIs with ASP.NET",  
      "subtitle": "Harnessing the Power of the Web",  
      "author": "Glenn Block, et al.",  
      "published": "2014-04-07T00:00:00.000Z",  
      "publisher": "O'Reilly Media",  
      "pages": 538,  
      "description": "Design and build Web APIs for a broad range of clients—including browsers and mobile devices—that can adapt to change over time. This practical, hands-on guide takes you through the theory and tools you need to build evolvable HTTP services with Microsoft’s ASP.NET Web API framework. In the process, you’ll learn how design and implement a real-world Web API.",  
      "website": "https://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/index.html"  
    }  
  ]  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw JSON Path doesn't do this, but depending on the implementation you're using, it *might* be supported.

We're currently in progress [writing a formal specification](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-jsonpath).  One of the open issues is the [breadth of expression support](https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-jsonpath/issues/17) we want.  Feel free to add a comment.  Once the spec is defined and published, I imagine most implementations will update to adhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It sounds strange to me that such a basic and useful feature is still no supported.

Comment: It's less about it not being supported and more about there's not a formal spec in which it _could_ be supported.  This means that implementors need to go outside of the accepted definition (which is a blog post) to create this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

As [@gregsdennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/878701/gregsdennis) said, this is totally implementation-dependent as of now.

In a given JSONPath implementation,

1. this functionality does not exist
2. there is a `contains()` function or similar,
   e.g. in Jawways syntax: `$..[?(@.title contains 'Java')]`
3. there is a regular expression feature that allows substring matches,
   e.g again Jayway's Jsonpath has a `=~` regex filter: `$..[?(@.title =~ /.*Java.*?/)]`
4. Divert into script evaluation in a filter (JavaScript, absent in most other host languages),
   e.g. in Goessner's and any JS implementation:
   `$..[?(@.title && @.title.includes('Java'))]`
   Note: `includes()` is an ES6 function, the actual JSONPath syntax is also a bit idiosyncratic.

Christoph Burgmer maintains a nice [JSONPath comparison](https://cburgmer.github.io/json-path-comparison/) table.

Comment: Thank you!
I tried this on https://jsonpath.com/ JSONPath Online Evaluator and I see that only $..[?(@.title && @.title.includes('Java'))] works and works correct!
$..[?(@.title =~ /.*Java.*?/)] gives wrong output. number of outputs are even more than input
$..[?(@.title contains 'Java')] looks like wrong expression. output presents "No match"

Comment: @Eliyahu My pleasure. The script eval example works on the evaluator above because the site is using JSONPath-Plus (which was derived from Goessner's JS) written in JavaScript under the hood (https://github.com/ashphy/jsonpath-online-evaluator/blob/ebc361377d1f72a43d96bbde6318792ddc3d00a8/package.json). You can try other implementations here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ e.g. Jayway's.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extract the value using rest assured you can use this part of the code for getting the needed values.

```
 .get("/endpooint")
      .then()
      .extract()
      .path("books.find{it.title =~ 'Java'}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIKE in jsonpath this way:

```
$..[?(@.title like_regex '.*Java.*')]
```