# Wiremock matchesJsonPath checking array values ignoring the order

Tags: jsonpath, wiremock

I am trying to improve the code to prevent errors. I have a couple of requests that can come in these forms, 1:

```
 {
   "idUser": "1234",,
   "ids": ["3", "1"]
}
```

or 2:

```
{
  "idUser": "1234",,
  "ids": ["1", "3"]
}
```

And I have this Json Match:

```
{
  "request": {
    "urlPath": "mypath/rest/",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "matchesJsonPath": {
          "expression": "$..ids[0]",
          "contains": "1"
        }
      },
      {
        "matchesJsonPath": {
          "expression": "$..ids[1]",
          "contains": "3"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
  }
}
```

How can I make a "contains" in a regex that ignores the order of ids. I have tried :

```
 "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@..ids =~ /[1-3]+/]"
    
    {
      "matchesJsonPath": {
         "expression": "$..ids",
         "contains": "1"
       }
    },
    {
       "matchesJsonPath": {
         "expression": "$..ids",
         "contains": "3"
       }
    }
```

** In case 1 it would not work and in case 2 it would.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65570454/878701

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is coming from your expression, but I'm not a jsonPath expert. I don't think you need to use the `expression/includes` notation. Something like this should work:

```json
[{
    "matchesJsonPath": "$.ids[?(@ == '1')]"
},
{
    "matchesJsonPath": "$.ids[?(@ == '3')]"
}]
```

I tested this out and if you have `"ids": ["1", "3"]` or `"ids": ["3", "1"]`, it will return a match. If you only have `"ids": ["1"]` or `"ids": ["3"]`, it won't return a match.